# Intersection and Union of Sets -- Inverses

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a project which is causing me to briefly read up on the union, intersection, and complement of Sets. From the understanding I have, I think the following statement is true:

If I have sets A and B
  then the Intersection of A and B is equal to the Complement of the Union of the Complements of A and B

If this is true, that works great for me!
  If this is false, how come? I must be understanding something incorrectly!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In notation, do you mean to say $A\cap B=\overline{\overline A\cup\overline B}$ (where the bar means complement)?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct notation for my wording

Comment: (Or, in other notation, $A\cap B=(A'\cup B')'$, since no one agrees on how to write complements.)

Comment: That notation seems more readable to me! definitely correct translation of my words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De Morgan's laws, for sets, are:
\begin{align}
(A\cup B)'&=A'\cap B'\\
(A\cap B)'&=A'\cup B'
\end{align}
Take the complement of the second one. (Note that $(X')'=X$ for all sets $X$.)
$$A\cap B=(A'\cup B')'$$

Comment: There's also a version of the De Morgan laws for logic. Specifically:$$\text{not }(a\text{ and }b)=(\text{not }a)\text{ or }(\text{not }b)$$and the same for "and" and "or" switched.

Answer (score 1):

That is true, you have it right. By De Morgan's laws, writing $\sim A$ for the complement of $A$:

$$
\begin{align}
\sim\!\ (A \cup B) &= \space{\sim\! A \space \cap \sim\! B} \\
\sim\!\ (A \cap B) &= \space{\sim\! A \space \cup \sim\!B} \\
\end{align}
$$
Because $\sim \sim\! A = A$, the statement you mention is true.

I used $\sim\! A$ for complement because (*) it's simple, and (**) it's much more readable than $U \setminus A$ when used multiple times, especially as there's been no mention of a "universe" $U$, and (***) it's least likely to be overloaded (as a unary operator) with another meaning ($\overline A$ and $A^c$ can mean closure of $A$, $A'$ can mean the limit points of $A$, $- A$ can mean $\{-a \mid a \in A\}$).

Comment: Other notations include $A^c$ and $\complement A$. Honestly, you can just write whatever.

Comment: @Akiva Weinberger Pretty much! within reason anyway. Other than \setminus, whichever reasonable one you use, you can be sure that someone else uses it for *closure*.

Comment: And $-A$ probably would mean $\{x\mid x=-a,a\in A\}$ in some contexts (subsets of rings or vector spaces, for example). And $A'$ is the set of limit points.

Comment: I almost used ~ $ A$  (this time!) but it's too indistinct.

Comment: `\sim\!A` $\sim\!A$

Comment: Yyyeah that is a nice strong tilde. And that's fairly unambiguous / not overloaded.

Comment: It's not overloaded? $\sim$ is used all the time for equivalence relations. If $\sim\!A$ is equivalent to $\sim\!B$, are we to write ${\sim\!A}\sim{\sim\!B}$?

Comment: Well, less likely to be overloaded as a unary operator. Yes it's a great eq rel symbol. $\sim\! A \sim \: \sim\! B$ made me laugh.

Comment: As long as we're breaking math, I'd just like to point out that, _technically_, $\sim$ can be used as a variable name. And, of course:$${\sim\!{\sim}}\sim{\sim\!{\sim}}$$by the reflexive property.

Comment: Um, sure -- in a theorem prover written in APL. In any case, *Plough through, though enough cough.*